# Only the month of february is not rendering perfectly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I am in the middle of trying to build a calendar that shows events as well.
The design and making the calendar dynamic is inspired by
[this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1yMqPyYeAo)

I successfully added the events, but only the month of February is not rendering perfectly. I can't figure out why. 
I checked every variables and methods setting the month as January and February and March, but I can't find the error. Every other month is rendering perfectly. Sorry I am new to javascript so forgive my noob code.
Here's my working code snippet:

```js
const date = new Date();

const renderCalendar = () => {
  date.setDate(1);

  const listEvents = {
    "January": {
      "16": ["Birthday", "Seema Sinha"],
      "25": ["Anniversary", "Seema Sinha"]
    },
    "February": {
      "22": ["Birthday", "Prateek Sinha"]
    },
    "March": {
      "14": ["Birthday", "Ajay Kumar Sinha"]
    },
    "April": {
      "30": ["Birthday", "Sweta Kumari"]
    },
    "May": {
      "17": ["Birthday", "Pradeep Kumar"]
    },
    "June": {
      "10": ["Birthday", "Abha Sinha"],
      "18": ["Anniversary", "Lalita Sinha"],
      "27": ["Anniversary", "Jyoti Sinha"]
    },
    "August": {
      "10": ["Birthday", "Sachin Sinha"]
    },
    "September": {
      "26": ["Birthday", "Runnu Sinha"],
      "28": ["Birthday", "Prabhat Kumar", "Pratyaksha Sinha"]
    },
    "October": {
      "2": ["Birthday", "Pranay Sinha"]
    },
    "November": {
      "4": ["Birthday", "Prajjwal Sinha"],
      "22": ["Anniversary", "Abha Sinha"],
      "23": ["Birthday", "Lalita Sinha"]
    },
    "December": {
      "10": ["Birthday", "Jyoti Sinha"],
      "1": ["Birthday", "Pranav Sinha"],
      "25": ["Birthday", "Bhavya Sinha"],
      "26": ["Birthday", "Pravin Kumar"]
    }
  };


  const monthDays = document.querySelector(".days");

  const lastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDate();

  const prevLastDay = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    0
  ).getDate();

  const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();

  const lastDayIndex = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    0
  ).getDay();

  const nextDays = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;

  const months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  document.querySelector(".date h1").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];

  document.querySelector(".date p").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString();

  let days = "";

  for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--) {
    days += `<div class="prev-date">${prevLastDay - x +1}</div>`;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
    if (listEvents.hasOwnProperty(months[date.getMonth()]) && listEvents[months[date.getMonth()]].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      var thisMonthEvents = listEvents[months[date.getMonth()]];
      if (thisMonthEvents[i][0] === "Birthday" && i === new Date().getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) {
        days += `<div class="today"><i class="fas fa-birthday-cake" style="color: #CBAB1A"></i></div>`
      } else if (thisMonthEvents[i][0] === "Anniversary" && i === new Date().getDate() &&
        date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) {
        days += `<div class="today"><i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i></div>`
      } else if (thisMonthEvents[i][0] === "Birthday") {
        days += `<div class="normal-dates"><i class="fas fa-birthday-cake" style="color: #CBAB1A"></i></div>`
      } else if (thisMonthEvents[i][0] === "Anniversary") {
        days += `<div class="normal-dates"><i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:red;"></i></div>`
      }
    } else if (
      i === new Date().getDate() &&
      date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()
    ) {
      days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
    } else {
      days += `<div class="normal-dates">${i}</div>`;
    }
  }

  for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
    days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
    monthDays.innerHTML = days;
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(".normal-dates").forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", event => {
      var targetDate = new Date();
      targetDate.setDate(event.target.textContent);
      targetDate.setMonth(date.getMonth());
      if (listEvents.hasOwnProperty(months[targetDate.getMonth()])) {
        var eventsThisMonth = listEvents[(months[targetDate.getMonth()])];
        if (eventsThisMonth.hasOwnProperty(targetDate.getDate())) {
          console.log(eventsThisMonth[targetDate.getDate()]);
        }
      }
      console.log(targetDate.toDateString());
    })
  });
};

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  renderCalendar();
});

renderCalendar();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #12121f;
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.calendar {
  width: 45rem;
  height: 52rem;
  background-color: #222227;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.month {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12rem;
  background-color: #167e56;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.month i {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.month h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.month p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.weekdays {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.weekdays div {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  width: calc(44.2rem / 7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.days {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.days div {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  width: calc(40.2rem / 7);
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.days div:hover:not(.today) {
  background-color: #262626;
  border: 0.2rem solid #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-date,
.next-date {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.today {
  background-color: #167e56;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
      <div class="month">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
        <div class="date">
          <h1></h1>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="weekdays">
        <div>Sun</div>
        <div>Mon</div>
        <div>Tue</div>
        <div>Wed</div>
        <div>Thu</div>
        <div>Fri</div>
        <div>Sat</div>
      </div>
      <div class="days"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "February is not rendering perfectly"? I cannot see any difference/problem running your script...

Comment: @vitta when I cycle through the months to February I can see that it keeps the dates for the last month seen (either January or March depending on direction). This only happens for 2020, February renders the correct dates for 2019. Another bug I've found is that every date clicked on says 2020 in the console, even in 2019

Comment: Also doesn't update for "november"

Comment: @MattEllen Thanks for telling me. I am having trouble thinking about how to do that. But I will make sure to correct it.

Comment: @freedomn-m I checked and I think it's not updating for October, working fine for November. But I didn't notice that earlier, so thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calendar is looking nice! Took me some time but I figured it out. The bug lies in:

```
for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
  days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
  monthDays.innerHTML = days; // <---
}
```

You misplaced `monthDays.innerHTML = days` inside the for-loop and since `nextDays` equals 0 in February, the DOM never get update. To solve it, you simply have to put that line of code out of the for-loop :

```
for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
  days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
}
monthDays.innerHTML = days;
```

Hope it helps and doesn't break your code! Keep it up!

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally solved my problem, and no my code didn't break xD